# The Cryptic Writing On The Wall

Tags: cryptic-clues, connect-wall

The goal is simple: solve the cryptic clues to get a Only-Connect wall, consisting of 16 words, which then must be grouped into 4 groups of 4 words each sharing a common property.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Investigate the beginnings of combinatorics (4) | Clean the dirty leader Donald Trump around us (4) | Learn muddled stream (6) | Look for StackExchange curve (6) |
| A dove-cat confuses lawyer (8) | Domestic animal behind vehicle that lies on the floor (6) | Source of life; for example, great leader (3) | Overflow cuisine, around fifty (5) |
| Wild fleas know small piece of ice (9) | Talented metalloid returning in America (6) | Notice broken post (4) | Option: carbon, hydrogen, oxygen and ice (6) |
| DNA, mouse or producer (9) | Tart is crazy painter (6) | Bunch of steps reportedly gaze at the situation (9) | A fruit begins life in modern Europe (4) |

---

Also, this is my first try at cryptic-clues, so I welcome feedback!

Comment: As if Only Connect Walls weren't hard enough, you had to go and make it cryptic to boot? That's brutal.

Comment: @dcfyj One of the reasons behind it is that I wanted to include Trump somehow :D

Comment: Late to the party, but wanted to say that I liked "Wild fleas know ..." clue.

Comment: While I was asleep I missed an Only Connect puzzle that had cryptic clues? D:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got the easy ones:

> COMB, DUST, MASTER, ?
>  ADVOCATE, CARPET, EGG, ?
>  SNOWFLAKE, ?, SPOT, CHOICE
>  ?, ARTIST, ?, ?

**Note**: The cryptic clues have been completely solved in [M Oehm's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40822/25412) with detailed explanation. The wall is :

> ```
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  |    COMB    |    DUST    |   MASTER   |   SEARCH   |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  |  ADVOCATE  |   CARPET   |    EGG     |   FLOOD    |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  | SNOWFLAKE  |   GENIUS   |    SPOT    |   CHOICE   |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  | GENERATOR  |   ARTIST   | STAIRCASE  |     LIME   |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
> ```

I think Group 1 is:

> FRACTALS (Cantor COMB, Cantor DUST, Koch SNOWFLAKE, Sierpinski CARPET)

Group 2:

> LIGHT (SPOTlight, LIMElight, FLOODlight, SEARCHlight)

Group 3 (from Paul Evans):

> DEVIL (Devil's ADVOCATE, Deviled EGG, Devil's STAIRCASE, Devil's CHOICE

Group 4:

> ANAGRAM (Anagram MASTER, Anagram GENIUS, Anagram GENERATOR, Anagram ARTIST) (http://www.anagrammy.com/resources/generators.html)

Comment: We have a winner!

Comment: Well done getting ANAGRAM!  Not easy at all.

Comment: I have added the wall from M Oehm's answer (for the sake of somewhat-completeness) and accepted this. :-) I do hope people upvote M Oehm and Paul Evan's answers as well, since this was mostly a collaborative effort.

Answer (score 19):

Partial answer for the cryptic clues, definitions in bold:

> COMB: **Investigate** the beginnings of combinatorics - first letters of COMBinatorics
>  DUST: **Clean the dirty** leader Donald Trump around us - DT (leaders of Donald Trump) around US
>  MASTER: **Learn** muddled stream - anagram (muddled) of STREAM
>  SEARCH: **Look for** Stack Exchange curve - charade of SE + ARCH (curve)
>  ADVOCATE: A dove cat confuses **lawyer** - Anagram (confuses) of A DOVE CAT
>  CARPET: Domestic animal behind vehicle **that lies on the floor** - PET after CAR
>  EGG: **Source of life**; for example, great leader: EG (for example) + G (leader of Great)
>  FLOOD: **Overflow** cuisine, around fifty - FOOD (cuisine) around L (fifty)
>  SNOWFLAKE: Wild fleas know **small piece of ice** - Anagram (wild) of FLEAS KNOW
>  GENIUS: **Talented** metalloid returning in America - GE (chemical symbol) + NI (reverse of IN) + US ✻
>  SPOT: **Notice** broken post - anagram (broken) of POST
>  CHOICE: **Option**: Carbon, hydrogen, oxygen and ice - C + H + O (chemical symbols) + ICE
>  GENERATOR: DNA, mouse or **producer** - GENE (DNA) + RAT (mouse, sort of) + OR
>  ARTIST: Tart is crazy **painter** - Anagram (crazy) of TART IS
>  STAIRCASE: **Bunch of steps** reportedly gaze at the situation - STAIR, a homophone of STARE (reportedly gaze), + CASE (situation)
>  LIME: **A fruit** begins life in modern Europe - first letters of "life in modern Europe" ✻
>
>   ✻ contributed by [f''](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12408/f). Thank you!

The wall is:

> ```
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  |    COMB    |    DUST    |   MASTER   |   SEARCH   |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  |  ADVOCATE  |   CARPET   |    EGG     |   FLOOD    |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  | SNOWFLAKE  |   GENIUS   |    SPOT    |   CHOICE   |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  | GENERATOR  |   ARTIST   | STAIRCASE  |     LIME   |
>  |            |            |            |            |
>  +------------+------------+------------+------------+
> ```

Comment: Is this still a partial answer? It looks completed.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Well, it's still missig the second step, the Only Connect wall: to sort the 16 words on the wall into 4 groups of 4 so that all members of the groups share a certain quality. Jon Mark Perry has given two examples in his answer.

Answer (score 13):

A possible group?

> Devil - Devil's Advocate, Deviled Egg, Devil's Staircase and Devil of a Choice

Comment: Seems to all fit, but I've never heard of the last one.

Comment: Another right group! Just left to figure out the connection in the last! Well, my original intention was Devil's choice (which according to some sources mean a choice between to equally bad things), but yes, that's a bit obscure.